# ng-show TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I'm using `ng-show` to display an error if two input values are different - all works OK, but I keep seeing the following error in my console when the view loads:

`TypeError: object is not a function`

Code from the template:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="badpin">
The pins entered do not match!
</div>
```

My controller sets the following:

```
.controller('loginpinController', function($scope, $state) {
  $scope.badpin = false;
```

It seems it's not recognising `badpin` as a boolean variable, but as an object? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: i really do not think issue is with ng-show, does the error go away if you remove ng-show??

Comment: If I remove ng-show="badpin" the error goes away, but then obviously the div.error is shown! I think it's definitely to do with the `badpin` variable. But I can't figure out what's going on..

Comment: show us the code where you have written angular.module.... code

Comment: Your error must be elsewhere. The above code alone does not cause this error (http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/12852/). If you can reproduce on fiddle and/or show extra code, that would be great,

Comment: try $scope["badpin"]

Comment: I'm asking this because it happened to me just yesterday: Do you maybe use another `$scope.badpin` somewhere else in your code, maybe as a function or object identifier?

Comment: Could the `badpin` be a red herring? Are you sure `$state` can be injected  into the controller?

Comment: So I switched the version of angular from 1.3.15 to 1.2.14 (as this was the one being used when I started to create a plunkr) and the issue disappears! Does this seem correct?